# What is wrong with my SQL query which uses Joins and Unions?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

What's wrong with my sql query? I am trying to use a `Join` and at the same time a `UNION` to get all table from another table while joining other tables together based on a relationship ..

However I get the following error:

`"The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"`

My query:

```
SELECT a.ESN, a.UnixTime, a.Payload, a.Timestamp
                ,b.AlarmingStatus
                ,b.STxModel
                ,c.GroupID
                FROM STxMessage a
                JOIN STx b ON b.ESN = a.ESN
                JOIN GroupInfo c ON b.GroupID = c.GroupID
                WHERE b.STxModel = 190
                AND a.AlarmsChecked="y"
                AND c.AlertsMasterSwitch="on"
               UNION ALL 
      SELECT d.ESN , d.UnixTime,  d.Payload,  d.Timestamp FROM STxMessageArchive d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is selecting 7 columns where as the second query is only selecting 4. You need to make sure the second query is selecting the same number of columns as the first to make the `Union All` work.

```
SELECT a.ESN, a.UnixTime, a.Payload, a.Timestamp
                ,b.AlarmingStatus
                ,b.STxModel
                ,c.GroupID
                FROM STxMessage a
                JOIN STx b ON b.ESN = a.ESN
                JOIN GroupInfo c ON b.GroupID = c.GroupID
                WHERE b.STxModel = 190
                AND a.AlarmsChecked="y"
                AND c.AlertsMasterSwitch="on"
               UNION ALL 
      SELECT d.ESN , d.UnixTime,  d.Payload,  d.Timestamp, 'null' as AlarmingStatus,
      'null' as STxModel, 'null' as GroupID FROM STxMessageArchive d
```

Comment: @PHP_lover ;) I have added `'null'` as default values into the columns that we added to balance the two union queries. you can leave it as `''` empty too or even do `'0'` as well.

Answer (score 5):

The error message says it all.

When using `UNION`, the columns return by the combined `SELECT` statement must be the same, eg.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2
```

if the columns do not match, you can still combine it provided that you have to provide dummy data for the column, eg

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, '' AS col3 FROM table2
```

so in your query, it should look like this

```
SELECT  a.ESN, a.UnixTime, a.Payload, a.Timestamp ,
        b.AlarmingStatus, b.STxModel, c.GroupID
FROM    STxMessage a
        INNER JOIN STx b 
            ON b.ESN = a.ESN
        INNER JOIN GroupInfo c 
            ON b.GroupID = c.GroupID
WHERE   b.STxModel = 190 AND 
        a.AlarmsChecked="y" AND 
        c.AlertsMasterSwitch="on"
UNION ALL 
SELECT  d.ESN, d.UnixTime, d.Payload, d.Timestamp,
        NULL AS AlarmingStatus, NULL AS STxModel, NULL AS GroupID
FROM    STxMessageArchive d
```

Comment: @PHP_lover, remember that passing `NULL` is different with `'NULL'`. The first one is an unknown value while the second one is a string.

Answer (score 1):

hi this are the extra columns in your first query

```
 ,b.AlarmingStatus
 ,b.STxModel
 ,c.GroupID
```

you need this same columns in second query to do `union` or you need to remove this column to do `union` operation

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the first part has 7 columns, and the second part has only 4.  An unions needs to have the same columns on both sides. Either remove

```
b.AlarmingStatus ,b.STxModel ,c.GroupID
```

from the first part, or add (even bogus) columns in the second part.